# Duplicate methods in java.io.Console?

Tags: java

In [`java.io.Console`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html), there are two methods, [`printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) and [`format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), which appear to be identical. In the API it says

> An invocation of this method of the form `con.printf(format, args)`
>   behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation of
>   `con.format(format, args)`

So why have two methods? Is there a case where one is preferred?

EDIT: They've done this in java.io.PrintStream as well in Java 5

Comment: Seems that both are equivalent http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Answer (score 3):

This is for the programmer who come from different programming background. `C/ C++` uses `printf`

Comment: Hmm.. though of that, but just wanted to confirm it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An invocation of this method of the form `con.printf(format, args)` behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation of `con.format(format, args)` - [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html)

So there is no difference , but just for the convenience of syntax